# How to obtain previous and new value from Angular mat-select?

Tags: angular, angular-material

Hellow. I'm using angular 6, and agular material, and I have an array of strings, which I display in a mat-select form field.
If an user selects one element, and then another, I need to track what was the previous value and what is the new value.

So far, I've been able to obtain current value using $event.value, but I haven't found a way to store or obtain what the previous value was.

```
   <mat-select  placeholder="Choose..." (selectionChange) ="checkTitle($event.value);">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of Titles; trackBy: trackByFn" [value]="option.title">
              {{option.title}}
            </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
```

So far, I haven't come up with any ideas as to how solve this problem.
Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can handle previous and current value by pushing the value into a Subject, and observe this Subject using the pairwise operator. This operator will emit the previous and the current value of the stream.
 (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html)

example:

```js
export class YOU_COMPONENT{

  private data: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  checkTitle(value){
    this.data.next(value);
  }

  observeDataChange():Observable<[]>{
     // this return an observable of an array that contains [previous, current] data
     return this.data.asObservable().pipe(pairwise());
  }

}
```

Comment: This is very helpful. So, if I want to reuse the component, I'd have to create a Subject for each element? Or can I simply use the same checkTile() function?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have to create a subject for each element, or if you wana make your component reusable and provide this feature, you can wrap it into a custom selection component. This custom one will contain his own Subject that handle previous and current value. And it should emit these values. At this point you will get a new selection component that you can use everywhere and always emit two values

Comment: Is it possible to give the working sample for this.I am new to Angular and i am looking for this solution.Thanks in Advance for you help @SaifJerbi

Comment: This won't catch the first change. Only since the second.

Answer (score 10):

Complementary the Saif Jeb's answer, if you use a formControl or FormGroup to get/put the value, you can use formControl.valueChanges, that's

```
  <mat-select [formControl]="control">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food.value">
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>

  control=new FormControl()

  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.control.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(this.control.value),
      pairwise()
    ).subscribe(
      ([old,value])=>{
        console.log(old,value)
      }
    )
  }
```

It's necesary a startWith(this.control.value) for the first change emit the value

See [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wx5skp-9iqlga?file=app/select-overview-example.html)

Answer (score 5):

Another simple workaround is to use the `openedChange` from `mat-select` itself and save the current value. the `openedChange` will emit data as the mat-select opens and its `event` is a boolean.

```js
public onMatSelectOpen(form: AbstractControl): void {
  this.prevMatSelectValue = form.value.type;
}

public onMatSelectValueChanges(event): void {
  this.currentValue = event.value
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
  <mat-label>label</mat-label>
  <mat-select 
    formControlName="item"
    (openedChange)="onMatSelectOpen(form)"
    (selectionChange)="onMatSelectValueChanges($event)"
  >
  <mat-option *ngFor="let item of items" [value]="item.id">
      {{ item.name }}
  </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

To get the current value, you can use `selectionChange` from mat-select.

Answer (score 0):

There's a property for MatList [selected], which takes boolean value as in **true** or **false**.

So while updating or selecting a value. Create a key-value pair which will on selection set true.

Answer (score -2):

You could just simply have a variable, to which you store the previous value:

```ts
prevVal: string;

checkTitle(newVal) {
  if (this.prevVal) {
    console.log(this.prevVal, newVal);
    // do stuff
  }
  // after processing, store the new val as the prev val
  this.prevVal = val;
}
```

Comment: Where would you take the oldValue from ... thats the question we are trying to solve :)