# How to get old and new values of dropdown in Angular 10

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-material, angular-ui

I'm very new to angular and still in basic phase.

I'm trying to get both old and new values when a dropdown is selected but not sure how to do it.
I was able to get new value but not the old one.

Need to pass both old and new values to Angular function.

**body.component.html:**

```
<div class="container">
<mat-label>Destination 1</mat-label>
<mat-select #box (selectionChange)="removeFromPlanet(box.oldValue, box.newValue)">
  <mat-option *ngFor="let planet of planets" [value]="planet">
    {{ planet }}
  </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

**body.component.ts:**

```
removeFromPlanet(old, new) {
console.log(old, new);}
```

But it's not working. Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have enough reps to comment but possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57513082/how-to-obtain-previous-and-new-value-from-angular-mat-select ?

Comment: Use NgModel https://dev.to/jwp/angular-ngmodel-model-and-viewmodel-5m

Answer (score 0):

You can handle previous and current value by pushing the value into a Subject, and observe this Subject using the pairwise operator. This operator will emit the previous and the current value of the stream. (https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html)

example:

```
export class YOU_COMPONENT{

  private data: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();

  checkTitle(value){
    this.data.next(value);
  }

  observeDataChange():Observable<[]>{
     // this return an observable of an array that contains [previous, current] data
     return this.data.asObservable().pipe(pairwise());
  }

}
```

Comment: This answer is a copy-paste from this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57513158/455716
That should be noted on it. Also, if the answer solves the problem, it means the question is a duplicate and should be closed.